# How to use VSTS to merge local branch into development/staging

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using source tree to commit and push my local changes to development branch/staging. but when I tried to merge my local branch into the development I got an error message saying

> The source branch has been modified since the last merge attempt.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried merging the development branch to your local branch before merging back to the development branch?

Comment: i havent tried doing that, but i will try doing that and see. thank you for the advice.